# How to change the Jenkins Home Directory from /var/lib to app and create a symlink for orginal location as job wont get affected

Tags: linux, jenkins, migration, space, home-directory

```
I need to change my Jenkins 2.89.3 version Home Directory from /Var/lib/jenkins to /app due to space constraints. I need to make sure , all jobs which are using the /var/lib/jenkins directory wont get affected by this migration. how to perform this operation and ran my jenkins job as expected

Current size of /var/lib/jenkins 5.1G
Move all contents to /app/
run jenkins jobs without any issues
```

Please help in this migration

Answer (score 3):

You can use a symbolic link to do that:

1. Shutdown you Jenkins.
2. Move all files from `/var/lib/jenkins` to `/app/jenkins`

   ```
   mv /var/lib/jenkins /app/
   ```
3. Replace `/var/lib/jenkins` with a symbolic link to `/app/jenkins`

   ```
   ln -s /app/jenkins /var/lib/jenkins
   ```
4. Start Jenkins again.

That way all the files are actually stored under `/app` but all paths to `/var/lib/jenkins` stay valid due to the symbolic link.